# Identify WOFF file properties

Tags: java, css, fonts

I have a list of font files all of which are in WOFF format. I have to parse all files and find out the respective properties(like fontFamily, fontWeight, fontStyle etc.) of that file to generate the CSS of format below to feed to the UI.

```
@font-face {
font-family: "Adelle";
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
src: url(C:/A.woff) format('woff');
}
@font-face {
font-family: "Adelle";
font-style: normal;
font-weight: bold;
src: url(C:/AB.woff) format('woff');
}
```

The concern is how do I read a given WOFF file in Java and identify their properties.

I was going through the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#createFont(int,%20java.io.InputStream)) and it said that it accepts only font files of type `TTF` and `Type-1`. Can anyone please provide me leads as to how can I address the problem?

Comment: What do you mean with "find out the respective properties "? You can trivially examine the OpenType header and OS/2 tables by running the font through something like [TTX](https://github.com/behdad/fonttools), would that be all you need?

Comment: I have elaborated on what I meant by "respective properties". Could you please elaborate a little more on "OpenType header and OS/2 tables by running the font through something like TTX". Is there any example/implementation which elaborates this?

Comment: I meant to install `TTX` (a command line utility) and use to convert the font to human readable XML format, then just read the `<head>` and `<OS/2>` sections of the resulting file for the information you care about (OpenType fonts consist of [meta data and real data tables](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/otff.htm#otttables))